# How to extract static method from lambda

Tags: java, lambda, static-methods

When creating an lambda, will create an private static method in current class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String> c = s -> System.out.println(s);

        String className = c.getClass().getName();
        System.out.println("Class Name of lambda: " + className);

        Method[] ms = Test.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for(Method m:ms)
        {
            System.out.println("Method in Test: " + m.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

got:

```
Class Name of lambda: Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789
Method in Test: main
Method in Test: lambda$main$0
```

When run this program, and when method "main" was called, JVM create lambda class named "Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789". This lambda class contain the private static method "lambda$main$0".

Now I'm building an multi instance async invoking system. I want use lambda as callback function. Service A invoking service B like:

```
Consumer<String> callback = s -> System.out.println("async call success! result is :\n" + s);
getService("B").asyncCall(callback, "this is some param");
```

Async invoking base on message queue. A send message to mq named "B", like:

```
{'callback':'Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789', 'data':'this is some param'}
```

Then B get this message and make response to mq "A":

```
{'callback':'Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789', 'result':'this is result'}
```

This response may receive by any A instance.

So this can't work if there are more than 1 A instance. A1 make an async call to B, then B return result to A2. But there are no same lambda class in A2.

So Can I extract the static method "lambda$main$0" from lambda class "Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789"?

Comment: If you're even considering that, you're doing something wrong. OTOH your question doesn't make it clear what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Why would there need to be "same lambda class in A2"? Why does B return data to a different instance of A?

Comment: Async invoking base on message queue. A send message to mq named "B", like: {'callback':'Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789', 'data':'this is some param'}. Then B get this message and make response to mq A: {'callback':'Test$$Lambda$1/1791930789', 'result':'this is result'}. This response may receive by any A instance.

Comment: Seems you want the simplicity of lambda syntax, but  not use lambdas to invoke them. That's where your approach is broken. Maybe you could get away by serializing the lambda.